# Throttling callable https firebase cloud function execution per user?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, throttling

I was not able to find any resources about this, hence wanted to ask if it is a good idea / necessary to add throttling to callable https cloud functions in firebase on per user basis?

Example, I want to limit one user to be only able to call https function every 5 seconds.

If it is a viable thing to do, how would it be acheived?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not any inbuilt per user throttling capabilities in cloud functions. You have a few options of doing your own:

- Put logic in your client side apps that tracks the amount of times a user is calling them and deny the call if too frequent

> Issue here is that if someone is trying to game you this wouldn't be 100% effective as they could use multiple windows, etc.

- You could implement a database solution where you track their usage and at the beginning of your function you check if they are violating your rate limit

> Issue here is you are still having the triggers of your functions incurring the costs.

- If it was a super big issue for you, I would recommend looking at using an API management platform such as [Apigee](https://apigee.com/api-management/#/homepage) where you can apply policies such as [rate limiting](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/develop/rate-limiting)

> This a heavy weight solution with an increased cost and so wouldn't do it unless necessary